# Is there a reason why the strcmp function isn't working nor the else?

Tags: c, if-statement

I have the code below and it isn't working with respects to the last two conditional statements: else-if and else. Using the strcmp, I would think that if both player1 and player2 had the same string, that this else-if body would be enabled, but it does not. Instead it loops again and asked to enter scissors, rocks or paper. In addition, entering something like hamburger and rock, does not activate the else part and instead asked for scissors, rocks and paper entry.

update1: According to the debugger and as far as I can see, it appears to be because one of the else-if earlier was exhausted. If I enter paper for player1 and paper for player2 then it enters in this one: 'else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)'. But it does not printf anything because there isn't another paper in its body. Then after, it loops again in the while loop (asking for inputs again: rock, paper or scissors), never reaching this: 'else if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)'

update2: If I place the 'else if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0) at the very top, starting it off with an 'if' statement. The program works. However, the else is still not working and its because of similar situation. Placing it at the top will not work, because it is suppose to encompass any other wording that is not scissors, rocks or paper.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char player1[25];
    char player2[25];
    
    while(1){
        
        printf("please type one of the following: rock, paper or scissors. Player1 goes first\n");
        scanf("%24s%24s",player1,player2);
        

        if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
            else if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
            else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");

        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");
            else if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");

        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
            else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");

        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
            else if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");

        }
        
        else if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
            else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");

        }

        else if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)
        {
            printf("nobody wins, let’s sing it again!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf("incorrect input, try again\n");
        }
        
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "this else-if body". Which if-else body? There are several of them. Please clarify by providing the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: You might try printing `player1` and `player2` or examining them in the debugger right after they are assigned so you know they are valid before you look for issues with comparing the strings.

Comment: According to the debugger and as far as I can see, it appears to be because one of the else-if earlier was exhausted. If I enter paper for player1 and paper for player2 then it enters in this one: 'else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)'. But it does not printf anything because there isn't another paper in its body. Then after, it loops again in the while loop, never reaching this: 'else if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)'

Comment: This has the same problem as your last question, i.e. a prior condition prevents a later one from ever being reached.  Specifically, if the text for player1 is valid, only one of the first 3 if/else block will be entered and none of the later ones.

Comment: Your comment is still not clear. "it loops again in the while loop, never reaching this". What does that mean? If it loops again it needs to get new input. Please show your exact run log. Emphasis is on **exact**. And please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67713461/edit) the post with updated info rather than put it in comments.

Comment: You still (from earlier question) need to review your flow logic. The code here has 13 outcomes (apart from bad input), but there are only 9 ways that scissors rock and paper can be played. You have tested the same combinations more than once.

Comment: Can you please just run the program and copy the entire log exactly and completely into the post?

Comment: what is 'log'? you mean the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an if/else chain, **exactly** one of the blocks will be executed, and it will be the first one where the condition is true (or the final `else` if none are).

To better illustrate, take the following code:

```
if (condition1) {
  // do thing 1
} else if (condition2) {
  // do thing 2
} else if (condition3) {
  // do thing 3
} else {
  // do thing 4
}
```

This is actually multiple `if` statements chained together.  If we add some redundant braces it will be more apparent how this actually works:

```
if (condition1) {
  // do thing 1
} else {
    if (condition2) {
      // do thing 2
    } else {
        if (condition3) {
            // do thing 3
        } else {
            // do thing 4
        }
    }
}
```

From here, it should be apparent that only the first condition that is satisfied will be entered.

This is why the `strcmp(player1,player2) == 0` block is never entered.  If player1 enters a valid string, one of the first 3 conditions will be entered and none others.

You need to move the `strcmp(player1,player2) == 0` condition and add the `else` inside each of the first 3 blocks.  You can also remove the outer blocks checking player 2's value since they are already accounted for in the blocks that check player 1's value.

```
    if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)
            printf("nobody wins, let’s sing it again!\n");
        else if (strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
            printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        else if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
            printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        else
            printf("incorrect input, try again\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)
            printf("nobody wins, let’s sing it again!\n");
        else if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
            printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
            printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
        else
            printf("incorrect input, try again\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(player1,player2) == 0)
            printf("nobody wins, let’s sing it again!\n");
        else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
            printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        else if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
            printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        else
            printf("incorrect input, try again\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("incorrect input, try again\n");
    }
```

Comment: @0___________ Seems I missed a few cases.  This should address it.

Comment: Quite horrible style to repeat the same code in every else :) Bad example for beginners

Answer (score 1):

I would change it a bit to make if-else a bit clearer. Using switch you can clearly see the winning logic.

```
const char * const answers[] = {"rock", "scissors", "paper"};
#define ROCK 0
#define SCISSORS 1
#define PAPER 2
#define NOTFOUND 3

int main(void) {
    
    char player1[25];
    char player2[25];
    
    while(1){
        
        printf("please type one of the following: rock, paper or scissors. Player1 goes first\n");
        if(scanf("%24s%24s",player1,player2) != 2) 
        {
            printf("Wrong input\n");
            continue;
        }

        int pl1, pl2;

        for(pl1 = 0; pl1 < 3; pl1++)
        {
            if(!strcmp(player1, answers[pl1])) break;
        }

        for(pl2 = 0; pl2 < 3; pl2++)
        {
            if(!strcmp(player2, answers[pl2])) break;
        }

        if(pl1 == NOTFOUND || pl2 == NOTFOUND)
        {
            printf("Wrong input\n");
            continue;
        }
        
        if(pl1 == pl2)
        {
            printf("Draw\n");
            continue;
        }

       
        if (pl1 == ROCK)
        {
            if (pl2 == SCISSORS)
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
            else if(pl2 == PAPER)
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
        }

/*      change below acordingly 

        if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
            else if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");

        }
        
        if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");
            else if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
        }
    
        if(strcmp(player2, "rock") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
            else if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");

        }
            
        if(strcmp(player2, "scissors") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "paper") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
            else if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");

        }
        
        if(strcmp(player2, "paper") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(player1, "rock") == 0)
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
            else if(strcmp(player1, "scissors") == 0)
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");

        }
        */
    }

    return 0;
```

But actually I would like to avoid if-else ladders if not needed:

```
const char * const answers[] = {"rock", "scissors", "paper"};
#define ROCK 0
#define SCISSORS 1
#define PAPER 2
#define NOTFOUND 3

#define MAKERESULT(a,b) ((a)*10 + (b))

int main(void) {
    
    char player1[25];
    char player2[25];
    
    while(1){
        
        printf("please type one of the following: rock, paper or scissors. Player1 goes first\n");
        if(scanf("%24s%24s",player1,player2) != 2) 
        {
            printf("Wrong input\n");
            continue;
        }

        int pl1, pl2;

        for(pl1 = 0; pl1 < 3; pl1++) if(!strcmp(player1, answers[pl1])) break;
        for(pl2 = 0; pl2 < 3; pl2++) if(!strcmp(player2, answers[pl2])) break;

        switch(MAKERESULT(pl1,pl2))
        {
            case MAKERESULT(ROCK,SCISSORS):
                printf("player 1 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
                break;
            case MAKERESULT(ROCK,PAPER):
                printf("player 2 wins, paper covers rock\n");
                break;
            case MAKERESULT(SCISSORS, PAPER):
                printf("player 1 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
                break;
            case MAKERESULT(SCISSORS,ROCK):
                printf("player 2 wins, rock crushes scissors\n");
                break;
            case MAKERESULT(PAPER, ROCK):
                printf("player 1 wins, paper covers rock\n");
                break;
            case MAKERESULT(PAPER,SCISSORS):
                printf("player 2 wins, scissor cuts paper\n");
                break;
            case MAKERESULT(ROCK,ROCK):
            case MAKERESULT(SCISSORS, SCISSORS):
            case MAKERESULT(PAPER, PAPER):
                printf("Draw\n");
                break;
            default: 
                printf("Wrong input\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for paper and then scissors it says 'draw'

Comment: @Jonathan simple typo try again if(!strcmp(player2, answers[pl2])) break; forgot to change 1 to 2  :)